# What are the minimum system requirements for running IBM Cloud Private (ICP)?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to run IBM Cloud Private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full System Requirements are in the [IBM Cloud Private Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/supported_system_config/system_reqs.html).

> ### Hardware requirements
>
> Minimum hardware requirements for a single node cluster
>
> - Cores used 2 or more    CPU power  >= 2.4 GHz
> - RAM    4GB or more *You need more than this minimum amount of memory, if you plan to run applications in this test cluster that might use a
>     substantial amount of memory.*
> - Disk space to install 40 GB
>
> Minimum hardware requirements for a multi-node cluster
>
> - Common clusters use 2 - 8 core machines. When it comes to choosing between faster CPUs or more cores, it is recommended to choose hosts
>     with more cores.
>
> Note: Elasticsearch is the database that is used to store monitoring,
>   performance metrics, and logs for containers. The recommended disk
>   space to meet the needs of elasticsearch is 30 GB. The path for the
>   elasticsearch data is /var/lib/elasticsearch/data. Ensure that enough
>   disk space is available for this data path on each master node.

Answer (score 0):

[Scroll down to requirements section](https://github.ibm.com/tpouyer/ICp-ce)

## Requirements

In order to successfully run the Vagrantfile your laptop will need the following:

- 4GiB of RAM

  - 8GiB of RAM will give better performance
  - Checkout the memory setting in the Vagrantfile to change this value for your laptop
    10GiB of free disk space
- VirtualBox 5.1.28 (tested on Mac 10.12.6, Windows 7, and Windows 10)
- Vagrant 2.0.0 (tested on Mac 10.12.6, Windows 7, and Windows 10)

### Tested on the following Operating Systems

- Mac OSx 10.12.6
- Windows 10
- Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can install IBM Cloud private (ICp) on one node (it can be both bare metal or virtual machine).
ICp now supports Ubuntu 16 and RHEL as a host OS. Base on ICp documentation you should have at least

- 2.4 MHz core
- 4GB RAM
- 6GB HDD

In that case you will be able to look at ICp but not sure that it will be enough to deploy any interesting application. ICp is IaaS and PaaS system to host application and you should initially decide what you want to deploy on top of it.